# programmatically set comment with attachment in fb connect for iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook

Using FB Connect for iPhone.  I'd like the user to be able to post a link with thumbnail to their profile.  This is done using the "attachment" property on FBStreamDialog.  In addition, I'd like to be able to provide a custom interface for the user to enter in a comment with the attachment.  (The comment would be the message that's associated with the "userMessagePrompt" property).

However, the only way I can see to do this currently is for the user to enter in their message in the FBStreamDialog popup.  Is there any way to programmatically set the comment in iOS?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this on the server side, as follows:

From my iPhone application, I make a POST request to a PHP script that includes the link to be posted, in addition to the user-supplied message.

The PHP script then uses the Stream.publish API to post the link to the user's profile:

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Stream.publish